# Django 1.6 transactions to avoid race conditions

Tags: python, django, multithreading, transactions, race-condition

I'm trying to use Django 1.6 transactions to avoid race conditions on a game I'm developing. The game server has one simple goal: to pair two players.

My current approach is:

1. User wants to play
2. The server checks if there is anyone else waiting to play.

   1. If there **is not**, it creates a GameConnection object (that has a unique identifier - uuid4).
   2. If there **is**, it gets the GameConnection identifier and deletes the GameConnection.

This is the code:

```
# data['nickname'] = user's choice
games = GameConnection.objects.all()
if not games:
    game = GameConnection.objects.create(connection=unicode(uuid.uuid4()))
    game.nick1 = data["nickname"]
    game.save()

    response = HttpResponse(json.dumps({'connectionId': game.connection, 'whoAmI': 1,  'nick1': game.nick1, 'nick2': ""}))
else:
    game = games[0]
    conn = game.connection
    nick1 = game.nick1
    nick2 = data["nickname"]
    game.delete()
    response = HttpResponse(json.dumps({'connectionId': conn, 'whoAmI': 2,  'nick1': nick1, 'nick2': nick2}))

return response
```

Obviously there is a race condition on the code above. As this code is not atomic, it can happen that:

- A checks for game connections. Finds none.
- A creates a game connection.
- B checks for game connections. Finds one (A).
- C checks for game connections. Finds one (A).
- B gets A's connection identifier and starts a game.
- C gets A's connection identifier and starts a game.

I tried do but this whole block under `with transaction.atomic():`, or to use the `@transaction.atomic` decorator. But still, I am able to reproduce the race condition.

I am sure there is something about the transaction dynamics I am missing here. Can anyone shed a light?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but as per my understanding, the atomic transactions apply for writes. In your case, you possibly want to use some kind of mutex locks to ensure only one pairing happens at a time. This is similar to @synchronized in Java. Not efficient at all performance wise though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Sai is on track... the key is that the lock/mutex won't occur until a write (or delete). As coded, there will always be a time between "discovery" (read) of the pending connection and "claim" (write/lock) of the pending connection, with no way to know that a connection is in the process of being claimed.

If you are using PostgreSQL (pretty sure MySQL supports it, too), you can force the lock with "select for update", which will prevent another request from getting the same row until the transaction completes:

```
game = GameConnection.objects.all()[:1].select_for_update()
if game:
    #do something, update, delete, etc.
else:
    #create
```

Final note - consider something other than `all()` to be explicit about which game might be picked up (e.g., order by a "created" timestamp or something). Hope that helps.